# Ler formato Json Angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript, front-end, angularjs-directives, angular-material

minha api retorna um formato de json da seguinte forma

```
{
  "Errors": [],
  "Result": [
    {
      "CompanyName": "teste inicio",
      "FantasyName": "inicio"
    },
    {
      "CompanyName": "teste meio",
      "FantasyName": "meio"
    },
    {
      "CompanyName": "teste final",
      "FantasyName": "fim"
    }
  ],
  "Message": "Solicitação atendida com sucesso!"
}
```

até aqui tranquilo, usando Angular 9 meu serviço que faz o consumo em minha API

```
 read(): Observable<Restaurant[]>{
 return this.http.get<Restaurant[]>(this.baseUrl);
```

meu arquivo do componente.ts onde faz a consulta em meu serviço

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this.restaurantService.read().subscribe(restaurants => {
  this.restaurants = restaurants
  console.log(restaurants)
})
```

no console do navegador ele exibe tranquilamente o retorno da API conforme já exemplificado no início, quando vou exibir em tela os dados retornados em "Result:" ou mostrar o valor em "Message", retoma a seguinte mensagem

```
error TS2339: Property 'Result' does not exist on type 'Restaurant[]'
```

Segue o código HTML

```
<ul>
<li *ngFor="let item of restaurants">
    {{ item.restaurants }}
</li>
</ul>
```

Tanto colocando o "Result" no .html quando no .ts do componete o erro é o mesmo.

Comment: Sim, vai dar erro mesmo! Na hora que o Html é renderizado o retorno da Api pode ainda não ter sido resolvido (por estar acessando dados de uma api o retorno é assíncrono) logo o erro.

Comment: Alguma sugestão de como resolver, apesar do erro mostrado ele acaba mostrando em tela os dados quando coloco o  "Result" direto no ngFor

Comment: Poderia postar a declaração da variável **restaurants**?

Comment: Sim, restaurants: Restaurant[]

Comment: Removi a resposta, pq achava que era um problema, mas, pelo visto aí deve estar acontecendo outro problema, e como não dá para testar creio não saber como ajudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essa mensagem é porquê não foi definido o '**Result**' no restaurants.
Tente fazer essa forma:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.restaurantService.read().subscribe((restaurants:any) => {
         this.restaurants = restaurants.Result
    })
}
```